# Problem with Games on Flash and Wine

Tags: ati, video, games

I started using Ubuntu 4 days ago and I really like it since I got bored with Windows.

But as always, I am playing a game via the internet like Backyard Monsters on Facebook or Moba like League of Legends but there's several problems. Flash games are running very slowly, it's like loading under 2 fps for both chromium and Firefox, whilst I can watch YouTube videos without any problems :(

I tried to look for solution like updating Flash or increasing my cache but always nothing. Same for League of Legend I succeed to run it after 2 days Googling. I am running it under PlayOnLinux with wine 1.5 and it shows between 10fps and 30 fps with very low options. I was running it perfectly with min 60 fps with high options running under ubuntu 12.10.

I have 8GB RAM and an ati Radeon HD 4530. I have a doubt that Linux didn't correctly install my graphics card anyways when I go to software source > additional driver I can find anything to install or has this happened because I choose a free version of Ubuntu?

(sorry for my English i hope you understand me to help me fast)

(i never want go back to Windows coz it's **** keep linux for ever :) \m/)

Answer (score 3):

This really sounds like a problem with your graphics driver. Try installing fglrx-installer-updates via the ubuntu software center or via the commandline (`sudo apt-get install fglrx-installer-updates`). After a reboot the driver should be working.

If this doesn't work, maybe the newest driver from AMD could work, see more information here: (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI).

If this doesn't work either, someone else has to help you.